# asp.net core 2.1 not binding properties to model onPost

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, nullreferenceexception, model-binding

Report.cshtml

```
@{
        @if (Model.ShowResults)
        {
            @if (Model.myCount > 0)
            {
                <div id="divResults">
                    <table id="tbl1">
                        <thead class="thead-dark customcolor1">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Category</th>
                                <th>Year</th>
                                <th>Month</th>
                                <th>Type</th>
                                <th>Batch No</th>
                                <th class="text-right">Amount</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody class="cfont">
                            @foreach (TestHelp.Classes.TestReportModel item in Model.ReportLists)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="result">
                                        @item.Category
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="result">
                                        @item.Year
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="result">
                                        @item.Month
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="result">
                                        @item.Type
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="result">
                                        @item.BatchNo
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @String.Format("{0:0000000000.00000}", @item.AccountNo)
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="row border-top border-dark">
                    <div class="col pt-2 text-left">
                        <b>Reported By: </b>@ViewData["reportedBy"]
                    </div>
                    <div class="col pt-2 text-right">
                        <b>Reported On: </b>@ViewData["reportDate"]
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
            else if (Model.errorText.ToString() != "")
            {
                <div class="row border-dark border-top">
                    <div class="col pt-2 text-center">
                        <table id="tblZeroRecords" class="text-center">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p class="text-danger">@ViewData["errorMessage"]</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row border-top border-dark">
                    <div class="col pt-2 text-left">
                        <b>Reported By: </b>@ViewData["reportedBy"]
                    </div>
                    <div class="col pt-2 text-right">
                        <b>Reported On: </b>@ViewData["reportDate"]
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
            else
            {
                <div class="row border-dark border-top">
                    <div class="col pt-2 text-center">
                        <table id="tblZeroRecords" class="text-center">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p class="text-danger">No Data found</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row border-top border-dark">
                    <div class="col pt-2 text-left">
                        <b>Reported By: </b>@ViewData["reportedBy"]
                    </div>
                    <div class="col pt-2 text-right">
                        <b>Reported On: </b>@ViewData["reportDate"]
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        }
    }
```

Report.cshtml.cs

```
public class ReportModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public List<ReportModel> ReportLists { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public bool ShowResults { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public bool myFlag { get; set; }
        public string errorText { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public int myCount { get; set; }

        private readonly ReportContext _context;

        public ReportModel(ReportContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Report Reports { get; set; }

        
        public void OnPost([Bind("textFromDate,textToDate")] Report report)
        {
            int year;
            int month;
            DateTime reportDate = DateTime.Now;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (report.textToDate < report.textFromDate)
                {
                    report.textToDate = report.textFromDate;
                }

                string textFromDate = report.textFromDate.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                string textToDate = report.textToDate.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                int.TryParse(report.textToDate.ToString("yyyy"), out year);
                int.TryParse(report.textToDate.ToString("MM"), out month);
                int lastday = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
                textToDate = month.ToString() + "/" + lastday.ToString() + "/" + year.ToString();
                
                ShowResults = true;
                try
                {
                    List<ReportModel> records = _context.Report(textFromDate,textToDate).ToList();
                    ReportLists = records;
                    myCount = records.Count();
                    if (myCount > 0)
                        myFlag = true;
                    else
                        myFlag = false;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    errorText = "Internal error";
                }

            }
            string UserName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToString().Replace("MMC\\", "").ToUpper();
            if(UserName == "" || UserName == null)
            {
                UserName = "DEFAULT";
            }
            
            ViewData["reportedBy"] = UserName;
            ViewData["reportDate"] = reportDate;
            ViewData["errorMessage"] = errorText;
            ViewData["count"] = myCount;
        }

    }
```

Now my issue is when I click submit it goes to onPost and gets the data successfully but the if block in Report.cshtml @if(Model.myCount > 0) executes even when myCount is 0 and because of which   @ViewData["reportedDate"] throws null reference exception. Please help me in resolving this issue. I have tried everything so that the if block doesnt execute when myCount=0.

Comment: Could you please share what you are getting on `ViewData["reportDate"] = reportDate;` while debugging it? As your `@ViewData["reportedDate"]` is string and `reportDate` is `datetime` could you please convert it into string. Let us know hows going on forward.

Comment: when myCount > 0, @ViewData["reportData"] works fine and displays date.

Comment: So was the problem resolved? Do you still have any concern on this?